# It won't accept command line after first run

Tags: node.js, server

I ran my first server and seems fine except that it won't stop running. I cannot even type anything else in the command line. I will appreciate any help[image]
Here is the code I ran

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => 
{
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('In the name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => 
{
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

But the problem is not the code, rather how to get back to this command line
$papus@QuantumOne MINGW64 /c/Projects/firstServer  so that I can start retyping again on the command line without closing everything down and restart the whole process.
right now it gets stuck on Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000 forever

Comment: What code have you used? Please see [ask], [mre], [help], [tour], and then [edit] your question to include more detail.

Comment: use the interrupt ctrl + c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a server and it is not supposed to stop after a time.

You can shut down by pressing ctrl + c

Or you can program a certain route that will kill it programatically (i did not say it should be done)

If you want to continue using the same terminal you can run the server in background (on unix systems it is done by adding `&` at the end of the start command)

You can also look at process manager for `nodejs` server like `pm2`